# regex: What is the proper way to detect an embedded string?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to locate any quoted string within a string.

For example:

```
You have logged "Slice of Paradise" in your diary.
```

The closest way I found was using:

```
"\w+\s\w+\s\w+"
```

This produces `"Slice of Paradise"`.

...which doesn't address ANY particular string.

What is the generic form of finding ANY embedded quote?

Comment: you mean this `"([^"]*)"` ?

Comment: Perfect!   
And so quick in response!   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a this regex:

```
"(.*?)"
```

Or as [Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) pointed in his comment you can also use a more performance regex:

```
"([^"])"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sB4vJ3/1)**

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee glad to help. Did my answer answered to your question?

Comment: Yes.   Very specific, on-the-spot.   Thanks!

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee great, would you mind marking your question as solved? :)